# SOQL Error "Didn't understand relationship 'Addresses__r' in field path..."

Tags: soql

Why am I getting this error? If I remove the Addressess__r references in the WHERE clause it works fine.

Error: Didn't understand relationship 'Addresses_*r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '*_r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

```
             SELECT ParentId, 
                Id, 
                Name, 
                (SELECT Id, 
                        Name, 
                        Contact_Name__c, 
                        Contact__r.Name, 
                        Contact__r.Email 
                    FROM Position__r 
                    WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Collegiate Ministry' 
                    AND Position_Title__c = 'Campus Minister'),  
                (SELECT Address_Line1__c, 
                        Address_Line2__c, 
                        City__c, 
                        State__c, 
                        Zip_Postal_Code__c, 
                        Country__c, 
                        URL__c, 
                        Email__c 
                    FROM Addresses__r 
                    WHERE RecordTypeId IN (:rtLoc.Id, :rtMail.Id)) 
            FROM Account 
            WHERE 
                Name LIKE :term + '%'
                OR
                Position__r.Contact__r.Name LIKE :term + '%'
                OR
                Addresses__r.City__c LIKE :term + '%' 
                OR
                Addresses__r.State__c LIKE :term + '%'
```

Answer (score 4):

based on the select part of your query it appears that addresses is a child of account, in which case, your where clause don't make any sense. you probably want some kind of semi-join type query, e.g.

```
select .... from account where id in (select accountId__c from address where city__c like :term)
```

Comment: Why would Position__r.Contact__r.Name work in the WHERE clause and not Addresses__r? They are both have the same kind of relationships with account.

Comment: Also are semi join sub-selects allowed when using 'OR'?

Comment: they didn't used to be, but i can't remember off the top of my head if that restriction has subsequently been lifted, you'd have to try it.

Comment: You can't. From the soql ref: [You cannot use subqueries in conjunction with OR](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm). Sometimes you just get [strange error messages](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/745/soql-expecting-right-square-bracket-found-or) when you try it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your schema, it looks like you have one Account, lookup to position and related list (many) Addresses.

In your final WHERE clause you are mentioning a related list of addresses ( Addresses_*r ) , since this syntax (*_r) represents a list, you are building an invalid field path. 
Basically, this list does not contain a field, it contains records which each may have a City field.

That is why you got the error.

take a look at the semi-join syntax: 
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/writing-shorter-queries-using-outer-joins

Answer (score 1):

If the relationship name is Addresses__r, then in your Where clause it should probably read

```
Id in (select Account__c from Address__c where City__c LIKE :term +'%')
OR
Id in (select Account__c from Address__c where  State__c LIKE :term + '%')
```

Comment: no, that doesn't work. =(

Comment: If you click on the Address__c field on Account, what does it say the relationship name is?

Comment: The name is Addresses

Comment: Are semi join sub-selects allowed when using 'OR'?